# Why would my Geyser/water flow change from hot to ice cold?

Tags: plumbing

I have a problem with my geyser (I think) 
When I run the hot water it goes cold within a few minutes then after about 30seconds it goes hot again. This is an ongoing cycle while the hot water is running... Extremely frustrated especially during a shower.

We have solar tubes on the roof and geyser wise max V11 control panel. It is connected to power as well.
Any ideas or suggestions?